# Проблемы с CTRL + V в HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть **<div>** с параметром **contenteditable** 
При использовании <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> в него вставляется текст с визуальными эффектами из других сред, что выглядит некрасиво и непрактично:

[image: До вставки]

[image: После вставки]

Как можно это исправит и вставлять только текст, без всего прочего?

*P.s. пожалуйста, не пишите мне про <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>, т.к. я хочу сделать всё автоматически и интуитивно*

Comment: Под этот вопрос, можно же было сделать воспроизводимый пример

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не то что бы проблема, а скорее особенность свойства `contenteditable`.

Вот такой вариант есть:

```js
document.querySelector('.clear[contenteditable]').addEventListener('paste', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
  window.document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
});
```

```css
div[contenteditable] {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="clear" contenteditable="true">Тут только обычный текст</div>
```

Comment: `document.execCommand()` имеет статус [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand).

Answer (score 1):

UPD: После переписки в комментариях, я решил переработать неполноценный вариант

```js
let edit = document.getElementById('edit');

String.prototype.splice = function(idx, rem, str) {
  return this.slice(0, idx) + str + this.slice(idx + Math.abs(rem));
};

edit.addEventListener('paste', paste);

function paste(e) {
  let buf, data;
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  buf = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
  data = buf.getData('Text');
  let startIdx = getStartIdx(edit);
  let endIdx = window.getSelection().toString().length;
  edit.innerText = edit.innerText.splice(startIdx, endIdx, data);  
}

function getStartIdx(el) {
  let start = 0;
  let sel, rng, rngTxt;
  if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
      rng = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
      rngTxt = rng.cloneRange();
      rngTxt.selectNodeContents(el);
      rngTxt.setEnd(rng.startContainer, rng.startOffset);
      start = rngTxt.toString().length;
  } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" &&
          document.selection.type != "Control") {
      sel = document.selection
      rng = sel.createRange();
      rngTxt = document.body.createTextRange();
      rngTxt.moveToElementText(el);
      rngTxt.setEndPoint("EndToStart", rng);
      start = rngTxt.text.length;
  }
  return start
}

//execCommand устарел данная функция используется исключительно для удобства копирования в примере
function copyContent (event) {  
  let div = document.getElementById("style");
  let range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(div.childNodes[0]); 
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  window.getSelection().addRange(range);      
  document.execCommand('copy');  
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  div.innerText="Ok";
  setTimeout(()=>{div.innerText="copy"}, 500);
}
document.getElementById('style').addEventListener('click', copyContent);
```

```css
#style{
  background:red; 
  width:50px; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#edit{
  border: solid 1px black
}
```

```html
<div id='edit' contenteditable='true'>Paste</div>
<div id="style">copy</div>
```

Comment: `document.execCommand()` имеет статус [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand).

Comment: Здесь он только для удобства и не имеет отношения к вопросу о проблеме вставки, копировать можно и через ctrl+c

Comment: Проблема еще в том, что ваш алгоритм не удаляет выделенный текст, который должен заменить по комбинации Ctrl+V. И он вставляет текст исключительно в конец текущего.

Comment: Кроме того, если копировать-вставлять путём drag-n-drop, то есть захватя выделенный текст мышкой перенеся в нужное для вставки место, событие paste не отрабатывает.

Comment: @DiD да можно придумать чего угодно. В вопросе только этих выдумок нет. "должен заменить" в вопросе было указано, или сам придумал?

Comment: Ну как что угодно, по вашему, именно так должен работать Paste, раз в вопросе не выложили главу из спецификации по вставке? Текст должен вставляться исключительно в конец? А если надо вставить в середину текста? А если нужно вставить текст вместо текста?

Comment: По моему надо т.з. внимательно читать "вставлять только текст, без всего прочего".. По вашему, к т.з. каждый должен сам придумать дополнение. Свой пример в ответе напишите, с учётом всего, что вы додумали и о чём автор вопроса не упоминал, ну и конечно же не используя document.execCommand()

Comment: Ну смотрите, у вас написано Paste. Попробуйте вставить любое слово **перед** Paste.

Comment: Сформулируйте и задайте свой вопрос, что бы я на него ответил, если захочу.